# .net core 3.1.1 production - 500 internal server error

Tags: iis, .net-core

I have two servers the with same code. i copied published folder from server A (which is working fine) same IIS config in both server

**in server B error is 500 internal server error.
but
server B runs dotnet myproject.dll** but not in IIS

I installed runtime and hosting bundle same as from server A.
this is my runtime, which are installed

````
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "netcoreapp3.1",
    "includedFrameworks": [
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
        "version": "3.1.1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App",
        "version": "3.1.1"
      }
    ],
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  }
}```
````

Comment: Solved, by reinstalling all runtime and restart

Comment: Great you solved it! It's possible your issue was that after installing the hosting bundle you didn't restart? You *must* restart IIS (Either with the IISReset command or restarting the server) after installing the hosting bundle. https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/12/23/hosting-an-asp-net-core-web-application-in-iis/